# Any way to install Windows on Linux PC without any Virtual Machine or CD/DVD/USB?

Tags: linux, windows-7, windows, usb

Long story short I got stuck with Linux on my PC. Can't find a way to install windows back on it. I've tried using my rooted android and boot windows 10 iso but it tells me I'm missing drivers. I've tried switching USB ports. I don't have a windows CD to install said drivers so I'm stuck in a loop

I'm using MBR

Summary

```
    Operating System
        Ubuntu
    CPU
        AMD Athlon II X2 250    49 °C
        Regor 45nm Technology
    RAM
        2.00GB Dual-Channel DDR2 @ 332MHz (5-5-5-15)
    Motherboard
        Acer RS780DV (AM2)  51 °C
    Graphics
        E55-2 (1280x960@60Hz)
        895MB ATI Radeon HD 3200 Graphics (Acer Incorporated [ALI])
    Storage
        149GB Seagate ST3160318AS ATA Device (SATA )    51 °C
    Optical Drives
        ATAPI DVD A DH16AASH ATA Device
    Audio
        Realtek High Definition Audio
```

Comment: You can download a Windows 10 ISO for free.  There is absolutely no way to install Windows 10 without a Windows 10 installation media built from a Windows 10 ISO.  Are you using GPT or MBR?  Please edit your question to include this vital information necessary to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I edited this question

Comment: Be sure CM/Legacy mode is enabled when you change the boot order of your devices to boot to the installation media.

Comment: Please answer this question

Comment: You have not provided enough information to answer the question

Comment: Please answer this question if added pc specs